# Unable to convert variable to GMP when initializing Bitpay client class (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bitcoin

I have generated my private, public and sin keys according to the [documentation](http://php-bitpay-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/keypairs/index.html), and added their respective paths to my yaml config file.
I can load the main bitpay class fine, however I cannot initialize the client class, as I receive the following error:

```
PHP warning: gmp_cmp(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - string is not an integer in /home/vagrant/laravel/vendor/bitpay/php-client/src/Bitpay/Math/GmpEngine.php on line 26
```

What would cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitpay automatically uses the encrypted file store, however the docs suggest that it uses the un-encrypted one by default. 
Changed it and it works.